# CSS Selector on custom element

Tags: css, angular, custom-element

Is there any contraindications on stylizing Angular2 custom element directly and selecting them with CSS selector ?

Example :

```
// HTML
<My-Page>
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <My-Footer class="sticky-footer"></My-Footer>
</My-Page>

// CSS 
My-Page {
    background-color: grey;
}

header {
    ...
}

.sticky-footer {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Good or bad practice ?

Answer (score 2):

While this is perfectly valid it breaks modularity. A component can style its own root-element:

my-page.component.css

```
:host{
  background-color: grey;
}

header {
    ...
}

.sticky-footer {
    position: absolute;
}
```

This will achieve the same thing and contains CSS that's vital to your MyPageComponent in the component.

Comment: ealier in RC4 :host child-component{ ..} used to work.. this is no longer working in stable release .. So i had to move the child-component{..} styles set by parent into child component as :host{...}.. Hope this helps someone..

Answer (score 0):

You should use ***piercing CSS combinators >>>, /deep/ and ::shadow***

```
styles: [
    `
     :host { background-color: grey; }

     :host >>> header{
       background:yellow;
     }

     :host >>> My-Footer{  
       position: absolute;
     }         
    `
],
template:
`
<My-Page>  //<----no need as this becomes your :host

    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <My-Footer class="sticky-footer"></My-Footer>

</My-Page> //<----no need
`
```

Comment: Be aware that `>>>` and `/deep/` (same thing) only work with angular's emulated Shadow DOM. It will break when you switch to native Shadow DOM. `::shadow` and `/deep/` are deprecated.

Comment: What if I want these styles being placed in my global css file (styles.css) and not in the component styles ? Example, I've got some issues due to the root custom tag <app> in index.html. I basically need to set height: 100% on it.